# Check against server time to display SQL entries - Radio Station DJ Rotator Plugin

Tags: plugins, php, mysql, apache

I'm building a WordPress plugin that will create a radio station "On-Air Now" DJ rotator.

**Working options panel I've built so far:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiYde.png

I've based the idea on a PHP case statement I wrote back in 2007 where you specify the DJ's start time which is then checked against the server time.

I know how to pull the image, description, and link out of the DB and display it. *I just don't know how to code the logic behind showing only ONE DJ during his/her scheduled TIME-FRAME.* e.g.; 6a-9a.

**Would it be?**

script: *"hello server, what time is it?"*

server: *"it's 6:25am"*

script: *"ok, database it's 6:25am...who is scheduled?"*

database: *"neal boortz"*

script: *"thank you sir. i will now write some HTML"*

**What I have built so far:** 
https://github.com/gregrickaby/DJ-Rotator-for-WordPress/blob/master/dj-rotator-for-wordpress.php

I'm not asking for someone to write it for me. Just shove me in the right direction with the logic. Maybe a code example or two.

Thank you!

Comment: This should be migrated to stack as it is a php question , not a wordpress one.

Comment: That's funny because at STACK they told me to move it here

Comment: This one can fall on either side of the fence, fine by me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have three parameters here:

1. Current server time
2. Schedule start time
3. Schedule end time

Then your task boils down to using [custom field parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) in query to request posts with two conditions:

1. schedule start hour is smaller than current hour
2. schedule end hour is larger than current hour